# While loop in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not used to writing Bash scripts, and Google didn't help in figuring out what is wrong with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read myline
do
done

echo "Hello"
while read line
do
done

exit 0
```

The output I get is:

```
./basic.agi: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'
./basic.agi: line 4: 'done'
```

and my `bash` version is:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Thank you.

---

Edit: The script works OK when the while loop isn't empty.

While I'm at it... I expected to exit the loop when the user typed nothing, ie. simply hit the Enter key, but Bash keeps looping. How can I exit the loop?

```
while read myline
do
        echo ${myline}
done

echo "Hello"
while read line
do
        true
done

exit 0
```

Comment: This simple read-loop works until "end-of-file". You can give an end-of-file by typing control-D.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't have an empty loop. If you want a placeholder, just use `true`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read myline
do
    true
done
```

or, more likely, do something useful with the input:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read myline
do
    echo "You entered [$line]"
done
```

---

As for your second question, on how to exit the loop when the user just presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> with nothing else, you can do something:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
while [[ "$line" != "" ]] ; do
    echo "You entered [$line]"
    read line
done
```

Comment: Thanks again. Next time, I'll post a new question instead.

Comment: `while :; do :; done` work (`:` is a synonym for `true`)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the `read` command in a while loop it need input:

```
echo "Hello" | while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

or using several lines:

```
echo "Hello" | while read line
    do
    echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to emulate a `do` `while` loop in Bash, It always executes once and does the test at the end.

```
while
    read -r line
    [[ $line ]]
do
    :
done
```

When an empty line is entered, the loop exits. The variable will be empty at that point, but you could set another variable to its value to preserve it, if needed.

```
while
    save=$line
    read -r line
    [[ $line ]]
do
    :
done
```

Comment: Dennis, did you mean to init `line` with something other than `''`? It appears to me that the loop will never start. My understanding is that until is simply the negative condition version of while in that it doesn't guarantee a minimum execution of one iteration. I may be wrong but the bash manpage seems to indicate that's the case as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are correct. Other languages have a proper `do` loop with a test at the end, but Bash does not. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491478/26428) shows how to emulate a `do` `while` loop in Bash. I've updated this answer to match that one.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? From the look of it it seems that you are trying to read into a variable?

This is done by simply stating read  the value can then be found inside of $

ex:

```
read myvar

echo $myvar
```

As other have stated the trouble with the loop is that it is empty which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a menu with choices as a infinite loop (with the choice to break out)

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("hello" "date" "quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "hello") echo "world";;
        "date") echo $(date);;
        "quit")
            break;;
        *) echo "invalid option";;
    esac
done
```

[PS3 is described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193659/in-which-situations-are-ps2-ps3-ps4-used-as-the-prompt)

Answer (score -1):

If you type `help while` in bash you'll get an explanation of the command.